# getBalance.sh on Amazon Mechanical Turk (mturk) Command Line Tools (CLT) returns an error

Tags: java, macos, amazon-web-services, https, mechanicalturk

Could someone help me figure out my mistake? Thank you in advance :) I'm trying to set up the Command Line Tool (CLT) on my Mac OS X Yosemite and I'm getting error messages.

My problem seems similar to the one in the link below, but not identical; I have changed "http" to "https" in the murk.properties file after installing the CLT.

[getBalance in Amazon Turk gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921598/getbalance-in-amazon-turk-gives-error/23921875#23921875)

**CODE:** This is what I entered in Terminal (initially thinking that my problem was Java location):

```
$ export MTURK_CMD_HOME=/Applications/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1  
$ java -version  
 java version "1.8.0_51"  
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)  
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)  
$ which java  
 /usr/bin/java  
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr  
$ cd /Applications/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin/  
$ ./getBalance.sh
```

**ERROR:** This is an excerpt of the error message I received

```
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException) caught when processing request: HTTPS hostname invalid: expected '176.32.98.23', received 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'
Retrying request
I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException) caught when processing request: HTTPS hostname invalid: expected '176.32.98.23', received 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'
Retrying request
I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException) caught when processing request: HTTPS hostname invalid: expected '176.32.98.23', received 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'
Retrying request
An error occurred while fetching your balance: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: HTTPS hostname invalid: expected '176.32.98.23', received 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'
com.amazonaws.mturk.service.exception.InternalServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: HTTPS hostname invalid: expected '176.32.98.23', received 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.AWSService.executeRequestMessage(AWSService.java:243)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.FinalFilter.execute(FinalFilter.java:38)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.Filter.passMessage(Filter.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.ErrorProcessingFilter.execute(ErrorProcessingFilter.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.Filter.passMessage(Filter.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.RetryFilter.execute(RetryFilter.java:115)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.Filter.passMessage(Filter.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.util.CLTExceptionFilter.sendMessage(CLTExceptionFilter.java:77)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.util.CLTExceptionFilter.execute(CLTExceptionFilter.java:62)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.FilteredAWSService.executeRequests(FilteredAWSService.java:172)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.FilteredAWSService.executeRequest(FilteredAWSService.java:152)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.FilteredAWSService.executeRequest(FilteredAWSService.java:116)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterServiceRaw.getAccountBalance(RequesterServiceRaw.java:1193)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterService.getAccountBalance(RequesterService.java:922)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.GetBalance.getBalance(GetBalance.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.GetBalance.runCommand(GetBalance.java:41)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.AbstractCmd.run(AbstractCmd.java:148)
    at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.GetBalance.main(GetBalance.java:28)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: HTTPS hostname invalid: expected '176.32.98.23', received 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
```

### The error message continues a bit. So, what do you think? Thanks again for looking at this. - Soon

mturk.properties file

```
# -------------------
# ADVANCED PROPERTIES
# -------------------
#
# If you want to test your solution in the Amazon Mechanical Turk Developers Sandbox (http://sandbox.mturk.com)
# use the service_url defined below:
#service_url=https://mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com/?Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester

# If you want to have your solution work against the Amazon Mechnical Turk Production site (http://www.mturk.com)
# use the service_url defined below:
```

service_url=https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/?Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester

```
# The settings below should only be modified under special circumstances.
# You should not need to adjust these values.
retriable_errors=Server.ServiceUnavailable,503
retry_attempts=6
retry_delay_millis=500'
```

Answer (score 0):

Guan, have you tried with an earlier version of the JDK (e.g., JDK-1.5?). I realize it's much older, but I'm curious if it's related to using the CLT on JDK 1.8. Just an idea.

Additionally, it would help if we could see the turk.properties file (please don't share your access keys or secret key) to make sure the endpoints are well-formed. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your JDK 1.5 suggestion. I'll try that soon. In the meantime, here's my turk.properties file; the contents shown above (right under my initial post) is the stuff below my access key & secret key:

Comment: I believe you need to uncomment the service_url address (which is set for sandbox, so you'll also want to change it to reflect production if that's what you're going for) but either way, you'll wan to make sure it's set for https://... since it seems like the error you're getting is an SSL error. Sorry for the (ridiculous) delay in responding here, I didn't notice your reply until just today.